# Access another class's public variable in constructor

Tags: java

I have class C1 and class C2. 
C1 has a public boolean variable b1.

The value of b1 is set in C1 and then I create a object of Class C2 in C1. 
ie in C1 I have :

```
b1 = true; 
C2 c2 = new C2();
```

Now in constructor of C2 , I want to make a decision based on the value of b1. 
How can I access the value of b1 (which is a variable of Class C1) in the constructor of C2 ? 
The constructor of C2 cannot have any arguements.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you have any arguments in constructor of `C2`?  Without it, you simply cannot do what you ask.

Comment: Is `C2` a non-static nested class of `C1`?

Comment: Note that a class can have multiple constructors, so you could retain the parameterless constructor and add a new constructor that accepts a boolean parameter.

Comment: @Aleks G there are ways to do this. C1 could be made into a singleton, or made static.

Comment: @JohnKane You're right, however why not just pass a parameter into C1 constructor?

Comment: @Aleks G I completely agree, decoupling code is a good thing. If the functionality of a class is dependent on a parameter then it makes sense to pass it in. I just wanted to say that it is possible to do what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

If the C2 class is defined as an inner class of C1 you can access its outer class like this:

```
C1.this.b1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this. You could also make b1 static, what @Logard suggested, or C1 could be made into a Singleton:

```
public enum C1{
    INSTANCE;

    public boolean b1=false;  

}

public class C2{

    public C2(){
        System.out.println(C1.INSTANCE.b1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In C2 make a object of C1 and then check.

`boolean check=new C1().b1`

Comment: That wouldnt get the current value of the existing instance of C1, unless thats not needed?